# How to serially get JSONObject from a txt file

Tags: android, json

I kept some JSON data in a txt file inside assests folder. Then i am reading the txt file and kept the result in  a string. Now i am trying to convert the string to JSONObject and get some data from each key. Below is the code.

========method for reading from a file:

```
private String readMyJsonFile()
    {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("myFile.txt"), "UTF-8")); 
             mLine = reader.readLine();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            //log the exception
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                 try {
                     reader.close();
                 } catch (IOException e) {
                     //log the exception
                 }
            }
        }

        return mLine;
    }
```

======= And inside onCreate():

```
String JsonStr = readMyJsonFile();

try {
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(JsonStr);
    JSONObject questionMark = JsonObj.getJSONObject("structure_details");

    Iterator keys = questionMark.keys();

   while(keys.hasNext()) 
   {
        String currentDynamicKey = (String)keys.next();
        JSONObject currentDynamicValue = questionMark.getJSONObject(currentDynamicKey);
    }
}
```

catch (JSONException e) {e.printStackTrace();    }

================================================
and the JSON data is:

```
    {"structure_details":{"x1":{"id":"54","name":"sh"},
                        "x2":{"id":"69","name":"dd"},
                        "x3":{"id":"80","name":"kk"}
                        }
     }
```

==========================================================

I am getting result but the problem is that i am not getting the JSONObject serially in **JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(JsonStr);** . The sequence is not the same as the **JsonStr**.

How to solve it?

Comment: this json structure is wrong

Comment: Its one of the objects among lots :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the iterator keys in a ArrayList of string. Then loop through each arraylist object and get the JsonObjects. Following is the code that might help:

```
 String JsonStr = readMyJsonFile(); //readMyJsonFile() is the same method you created

    ArrayList<String> sortedKey = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(JsonStr);

        JSONObject questionMark = jsonObj.getJSONObject("structure_details");

        Iterator keys = questionMark.keys();

          while(keys.hasNext()) {
                String currentDynamicKey = (String)keys.next();
                sortedKey.add(currentDynamicKey);
            }
          Collections.sort(sortedKey);

          for(String str:sortedKey )
          {  JSONObject currentDynamicValue = questionMark.getJSONObject(str);
          }
    }

     catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not JSON:

```
"structure_details":{"x1":{"id":"54","name":"sh"},
                     "x2":{"id":"69","name":"dd"},
                     "x3":{"id":"80","name":"kk"}
                    }
```

It is JSON:

```
{"structure_details":{"x1":{"id":"54","name":"sh"},
                      "x2":{"id":"69","name":"dd"},
                      "x3":{"id":"80","name":"kk"}
                     }}
```

and it JSON:

```
                       {"x1":{"id":"54","name":"sh"},
                        "x2":{"id":"69","name":"dd"},
                        "x3":{"id":"80","name":"kk"}
                        }
```